# How to retrieve error message set with setCustomValidity?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, constraints

I'm setting custom validity using HTML5 Constraints API like this

```
inputElement.setCustomValidity('This is custom error message')
```

Then I'm trying to retrieve the value afterwards, but it's not present in any of `ValidityState` object fields when I'm listing them. It just sets `customError` to `true`, but the message is not in there.

How can I retrieve this message from the input element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve it with `inputElement.validationMessage`.